# Installed DNN Module - Not showing in dropdown to give link

Tags: dotnetnuke

I had an link in my DNN site Menu - pointing to aspx page of my installed module.
I replaced this link with an external link.

And now i wish to change back to old one - aspx from module. BUT am not getting that listed in the dropdown

[image]

How to get that back or I missed anything ? I could found the module still in that EXTENSIONS.

Please suggest

Rigin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dnn module got 2 pages a view page and a settings page. So you must be sure that your module start's with the correct page.

So what you want is not possible the way you want it.

Best way for you is to control the page in your module. You can control this with for example a user controls(ascx). See image for a default module view.

[image: Default module]

Comment: Can you say , where this Menu ..links are stored in database for DNN ?

Comment: To change your start page(control) from your module you must be in host-->extension--> edit your extension and the module definitions there you can change the default start page(control) from your module.

Comment: No dear JK, I asked ... where these menus seen at top are getting stored ??.
these Home, Menu1, Careers, ContactUs....etc...

Comment: Admin --> Page Management

Comment: See ,, here you can view each Page that is appearing right .
And  > right clk on a menu > Page Setting > Other Setting Tab ... 

here you can find an Option "LINK URL" >>
Am Selecting "Page(A Page on you Site)" and I want to select an Module  here , its not appearing in that dropdown. Earlier that was appearing in dropdownlist , I changed to external URL , but am unable to change back . this is my issue.

Comment: You can't select a module! You select a page where the module is on! I can't help you further then that!

Comment: You last comment gave more idea +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be a little confused,

Modules are placed on pages, (One or mor module generally makes up a page.

Menu links refer to pages,

To add a module to a menu it must be on a page.

Once you have placed you module on a page you can select it from the select a web page drop down